# Strange If/Else Behavior

Tags: unity-game-engine

**Context**

I am making a mobile game in which the player is required to touch objects in a specified order. The correct order is determined in a List called clickOrder. To determine the current object the player is supposed to click, currClickIndex is used.

**Problem**

When touching a correct object, the debug text will display "Correct" for a split second, and will then immediately change to "Wrong." What I am unsure about is why both the if and else blocks are executed when only touching a single object.

**Code**

```
void Update()
{
    if (Input.touchCount == 1)
    {
        if (this.enabled)
        {
            Vector2 worldPoint = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
            RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(worldPoint, Vector2.zero);

            if (hit != null && hit.collider != null)
            {
                // check if the touched object is the correct one
                if (hit.collider.gameObject == clickOrder[MyData.currClickIndex])
                {
                    debug.text = "Correct";
                    MyData.currClickIndex++;
                }
                else
                {
                    debug.text = "Wrong";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at the log history? It should show both "Correct" and "Wrong" immediately after it. If that's the case, can you think of a way that can happen, and if it's the way it happens in your case? Hint: Update is called a lot of times per second.

Comment: The strange thing is that as soon as the object is touched, "Correct" will be displayed. However, this will immediately transition into continuous, multiple instances of "Wrong" so long as the object is still being touched.

Comment: MyData.currClickIndex++; tells you anything?

Comment: One more thing:  `if (this.enabled)` is redundant. If a MonoBehaviour is disabled, then `Update()` is never called. `if (this.enabled)` in your case can never fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As soon as the correct object is being touched, you do this:

```
MyData.currClickIndex++;
```

which moves you forward in the ordered sequence, and from then on, the previously correct object is not correct anymore. But you're still touching it.

If you want to avoid this, you need to move forward in the sequence **after** you've touched the correct object.

```
if (there are touches and the correct object is being touched)
{
      set a flag;
}
else if (a flag has been set)
{
      MyData.currClickIndex++;
      reset the flag;
}
```

Comment: I see! In my original approach, I was moving forward in the sequence when I was not supposed to, but by using a flag, I am now able to have correct control over the sequence. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Alternatively you can move forward in the sequence only on touch start and not for every update, moreover that shouldn't require a flag.